# How strict to be when using Qt framework?

Tags: qt

I'm building a Qt application that needs to use libssh, a SSH client library. libssh (understandably) performs its own network connections, however Qt has its own infrastructure for network connections (QTcpSocket etc).

Should I worry about these differences? Should I be trying to make libssh make network connections via QTcpSocket... Or if it works fine on the platforms I'm targeting, is that good enough?

Answer (score 0):

The only downside is that you have another library that your code depends on.
The primary rule though is if it works, go with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how the abstraction you get from libssh looks like. If it is a socket-like API, you could create an QAbstractSocket implementation for it. If it is just some structure or handle to read from and write to, you could create a QIODevice subclass. Most I/O can be implemented generically operating on QIODevices (instead of explicitely operating on QFile, sockets, etc.).